# Add Month and Year column from complete date column

Tags: r, date

I have a column with date formatted as MM-DD-YYYY, in the Date format.
I want to add 2 columns one which only contains YYYY and the other only contains MM.

How do I do this?

Comment: YOu can do `library(tidyr); separate(df1, date, into = c('month', 'day', 'year') %>% select(-day)` or with `base R` `read.table(text=sub("-\\d{2}-", ",", df1$date), sep=",")`

Comment: This is a duplicate problem surely of many problems beforehand, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once again base R gives you all you need, and you should *not* do this with sub-strings.

Here we first create a `data.frame` with a proper `Date` column.  If your date is in text format, parse it first with `as.Date()` or my `anytime::anydate()` (which does not need formats).

Then given the date creating year and month is simple:

```
R> df <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+seq(1,by=30,len=10))
R> df[, "year"] <- format(df[,"date"], "%Y")
R> df[, "month"] <- format(df[,"date"], "%m")
R> df
         date year month
1  2017-12-29 2017    12
2  2018-01-28 2018    01
3  2018-02-27 2018    02
4  2018-03-29 2018    03
5  2018-04-28 2018    04
6  2018-05-28 2018    05
7  2018-06-27 2018    06
8  2018-07-27 2018    07
9  2018-08-26 2018    08
10 2018-09-25 2018    09
R>
```

If you want year or month as integers, you can wrap as `as.integer()` around the format.

Comment: Can you please add the `lubridate` alternative too? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be to remove the substring with `sub` and then read with `read.table`

```
df1[c('month', 'year')] <- read.table(text=sub("-\\d{2}-", ",", df1$date), sep=",")
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(df1, date, into = c('month', 'day', 'year') %>% 
           select(-day)
```

Note: it may be better to convert to datetime class instead of using the string formatting.

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(date =mdy(date), month = month(date), year = year(date))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("05-21-2017", "06-25-2015"))
```

Comment: Please do not recommend using string functions for working on dates or times.  And `tidyverse` is surely overkill too.